If I put a cleaned bottle into my aquarium, can animals go inside it? Or will they drown due to how oxygen spreads?
If I put a bottle into a tank of water, and the entire reservoir has air pumps, will the air automatically spread throughout into the tank?
Sorry if this post is not chemistry. I was uncertain if it pertained more to physics or another science.

There are natural cavities where fish or other animals often hide and stay alive.

Fish don't "drown". In principle they could suffocate, but in such a small volume, where you actually pump air this would be very strange. Having some bottle hardly matters - it's not like it could magically block oxygen dissolved in water.

@Mithoron thank you so much. So they won't die if one of snails falls into the bottle/jar? I am starting to think maybe I am just being a bit overly concerned for their care, but really want to make sure I am doing the best for them.

It does'n't matter where the water is, the oxygen from the atmosphere will always saturate it so no more oxygen can dissolve.
